# My DataGrip IDE can't find MERGE function even though it is in postgresql 15.1

Tags: datagrip, postgresql-15

because of the interest we have in postgresql 15, my team and I would like to migrate to this new version. As we work with docker, I loaded the postgres:15 image instead of the old postgres:13 image and got it on my PC.
Now my problem is that I can't find a way to use Postgres:15 on my DataGrip IDE.

I can still write postgresql 14 code in DataGrip.

```
select version();
```

in a query console in DataGrip gets me version 15.1 [version response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYZS1.png) but new commands such as MERGE can't be found by the IDE.

I found out after some research that the old version persisted in a terminal call of psql so i deleted the old cluster because they had the same port and name and now when i call psql in a terminal, I can write in postgresql 15.1 but still not on DataGrip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a plan to implement it from 2023.1: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16310